# Symfony2 DateTime null accept

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine

So, I want to be able send a null option to my DOB field.

Here is my form builder:

```
->add('birthDate', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

And here is those field in my entity

```
 /**
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type="date",
     *     nullable=true
     * )
     * @JMS\Groups("single")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $birthDate;
```

When I`m trying to send a null I got an error msg

```
Expected argument of type "DateTime", "NULL" given
```

any ideas?

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Expected argument of type "DateTime", "NULL" given" at /var/www/server.local/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php line 253 



  $type = $trace[$i]['args'][0];
    $type = is_object($type) ? get_class($type) : gettype($type);
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Expected argument of type "%s", "%s" given', substr($message, $pos, strpos($message, ',', $pos) - $pos), $type));
}
```

}

Comment: When you are getting this error?

Comment: When submitting form whith birthDate field

Comment: and also have you made sure that the DB schema is in sync with the entity ?

Comment: I`m sure, schema in sync with DB

Comment: Since you are using single_text as widget, maybe you are using some js component that is not working. Could you try without it?

Comment: can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: Does the setter for your $birthDate look like this:
setBirthDate(\DateTime $value)?
If yes, change it to
setBirthDate(\DateTime $value = null)

Comment: Oh, you are a genious! Thanks to Emanuel Oster for the right answer!

Comment: Is there a way to have validation defined for entity **without** calling entity setters? EDIT: actually it is by adding `'by_reference' => true` to the form.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case, the problem was caused by PHP type hinting.
If you use type hinting (for instance `setBirthDate(\DateTime $value)`) then PHP forces you that you actually provide a DateTime object. Obviously, null is not such an object. To resolve this problem, it is possible to give `$value` a default value like this: `setBirthDate(\DateTime $value = null)`.

This is documented behavior and explained in the PHP Documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

Relevant passage:

> To specify a type declaration, the type name should be added before the parameter name. The declaration can be made to accept NULL values if the default value of the parameter is set to NULL.

Comment: Note: For PHP 7.1 you can also type hint it as optional nullable: `setBirthDate(?\DateTime $value)`

Answer (score 5):

The problem occurs due type-hinted setter as it is mentioned in the comments. There are two solutions:

**1.** Use `'by_reference' => true` on your form:

```
$builder->add(
    'birthDate',
    DateType::class,
    [
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'by_reference' => true,
    ]
);
```

**2.** Let your setter accept `null`:

```
public function setBirthDate(\DateTime $value = null)
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: Your first solution makes more sense. 2nd one is also working, but that will make the field hold unwanted data(null)

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass any values to it.  Make the field not required by doing this:

```
->add(
    'birthDate', 
    DateType::class, 
    array(
        'required' => false,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    )
)
```

Comment: How are you setting the form data? ->handleRequest($request); ?

Comment: No. As you see I'm using ORM annotations, so that's why your solution doesn't work for me, that's how I think

Comment: ORM annotations do nothing for validation, they're mapping to the database. If you were using @Assert\Datetime or @Assert\NotNull then I could understand the validation failure. Please use Symfony's recommended way of form submissions, [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)

Comment: It`s to late to use recommended way, because I already have a big working project.

Comment: Okay, so how are you setting the form data?

Comment: I actually can`t understand what you asking for(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109052/discussion-between-lms94-and-lunin-roman).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using DOB field in my project. Try this. 
My ORM file looks like this `<field name="dob" type="date" column="dob" nullable="true"/>`

```
->add('dob','birthday',array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker',
                'data-provide' => 'datepicker','data-date-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        ))
```

Comment: It`s not so simple for me. I have created a angular directive, that consist of 3 dropdown inputs for day, date and year