# Symfony DateType cannot handle null value despite NotBlank constraint

Tags: symfony, date, constraints, symfony4, symfony-forms

I am making a form with a `birthdate` field which must be filled:

```php
    ->add('birthdate', DateType::class, [
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(['message' => 'The birthdate is missing']),
            new LessThanOrEqual([
                'value' => (new \DateTime('now'))->modify('-15 years'),
                'message' => 'Must be 15 or older.',
            ])
        ]
    ])
```

The form is mapped to a `Preregistration` **Entity** which `birthdate` property must not be null:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $birthdate;
```

I am *"testing"* the form and its constraints by adding a `novalidate` HTML attribute to the empty form, to see how the back-end verifications would act. Despite the `NotBlank` constraint, I keep getting this error:

> **InvalidArgumentException:**
>   Expected argument of type "DateTimeInterface", "NULL" given at property path "birthdate".

---

The exception disappears when I remove the `widget` key from the `birthdate` field options (but I need/want to use this widget).

What could cause the constraints to be *"bypassed"* ?

Comment: May you can use datetime constraint (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html) or notnull constraint (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html)

Comment: The `NotNull` constraint does not change anything (the `NotBlank` does not allow `null` value by default). The `DateTime` constraint ensures a date format, which I won't need as the field is already a `DateType`. I tried adding an `invalid_message` option key, still get the exception.

Answer (score 2):

On your entity setter, allow it to be null

```
public function setBirthdate(?\DateTimeInterface $birthdate): self
{
    $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

    return $this;
}
```

Then use assert to validate it

```
    /**
     * @var DateTime $birthdate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $birthdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

i will try the following by removing the constaints from the form type and add it inside the entity.

and this is an example how i am using the forms with no validate tag

form type:

```
->add(
            'birthdate',
            DateTimeType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'birthdate',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
            ]
```

entity:

```
   /**
     * @var DateTime $birthdate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $birthdate;
```

setters and getters:

```
/**
 * Get birthdate
 *
 * @return DateTime
 */
public function getBirthdate(): ?DateTime
{
    return $this->birthdate;
}

/**
 * Set birthdate
 *
 * @param DateTime $birthdate
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setBirthdate($birthdate): self
{
    $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried lots of solution but these not worked for me.
I changed setter function of birthdate as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36601458/) and it worked for me.

Explanation given in above link is-

> In this case, the problem was caused by PHP type hinting. If you use
> type hinting (for instance setBirthDate(\DateTime $value)) then PHP
> forces you that you actually provide a DateTime object. Obviously,
> null is not such an object. To resolve this problem, it is possible to
> give $value a default value like this: setBirthDate(\DateTime $value =
> null).
>
> This is documented behavior and explained in the PHP Documentation
> (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

My setter function is like-

```
public function setBirthdate(\DateTimeInterface $birthdate = null ): self
{
    $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

    return $this;
}
```